# Button click to change text in focused textbox that was dynamically generated

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Using VS2013 I'm creating a website to collect some data on a tablet (using IE). I don't want to use the tablet keyboard so I created a numberpad out of asp buttons instead.  I need to know which textbox had focus in order to change the text to the value of the button clicked.

Here's my problem - the textbox is dynamically created inside a gridview template field that is also dynamically created when each row is databound.  So the field and the controls don't exist in the aspx page.

I can't figure out how to determine which textbox is selected before the button is clicked.
I believe this needs to be done client side using js or jquery, but I have never used these before.

I need a script that inserts the clicked number into the textbox that was most recently selected.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If (Not IsPostBack) Then  
        tfield = New TemplateField()
        tfield.HeaderText = "Count"
        GridView1.Columns.Add(tfield)

        Dim GhostTable As New DataTable
        GhostTable.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Count"))

        'Initialize table with 1 blank row
        Dim blankRow As DataRow = GhostTable.NewRow()
        GhostTable.Rows.Add(blankRow)

        'Makes the gridview reflect the GhostTable (currently 1 blank row)
        GridView1.DataSource = GhostTable
        GridView1.DataBind()
    Else
        'Occurs on every postback
        GridView1.DataSource = Session("GhostTable")
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    'Handles databinding of each gridview1 row and adds the textboxes to the template fields
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim tbxCount As New TextBox()
        tbxCount.ID = "tbxCount"
        tbxCount.Text = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row.Item("Count").ToString()
        tbxCount.Width = 100
        tbxCount.Height = 61
        tbxCount.Font.Size = 36
        e.Row.Cells(5).Controls.Add(tbxCount)
    End if
End sub

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Determine which of the gridview row's "tbxCount" was focused and insert the number 1
    'preferably this would happen on the client side?
End Sub
```

Sorry this was so long everyone. Just wanted to make sure I provided enough information.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to do this with javascript so I can't provide details, but I would think you could run something on the textboxes' onfocuslost (or onfocus for that matter) events that sets a variable to that textbox.  Then when the keypad button is clicked, you use that variable, which now references the last focused textbox.

Comment: I want to use the onfocuslost but that event handler can't exist in the code behind for a web application from what I understand. Thus the javascript need.  I think I might need to use something with the UniqueID in js, but don't know how.

Comment: Element events can be handled by the browser with javascript.  See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a self-contained sample of how you can handle the onfocus event of a textbox, assign the textbox to a variable when the event occurs, and manipulate the contents of the last focused textbox when a button is clicked.

`var lastTbox;` defines a global variable when the page is loaded, so it is not within a function.

```
<html><body>
<script>

    var lastTbox;

    function focusFunction(val){

        lastTbox = val;
    }

    function buttonClick(){

        lastTbox.value = "text";
}

</script>

<input type="text" id="tbox1" onfocus="focusFunction(this)">
<input type="text" id="tbox2" onfocus="focusFunction(this)">
<input type="button" onclick="buttonClick()">

</body></html>
```

Comment: Adapting this code is exactly what I needed.  Here's what I ended up using:
`function buttonClick(int) {
            lastTbox.text = int;
        }
` <input type="button" Value="1"  onclick="buttonClick(1)" /></td>

Plus in the vb code:
` tbxCount.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "focusFunction(this)")